# Get maximum memory usage of linux executable

Tags: shell, scripting, memory, time

I need a shell script which will retrieve the maximum memory consumption of a linux executable. The executable may spawn child processes using significant amounts of RAM which should be included in the total.

I've tried `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" /path/to/executable`, but this always yields `0` though using `ps` I can verify the process is indeed consuming significant RAM.

Why is `time` giving me `0` all the time, and how can I get the number I'm looking for?

Comment: How do you want to account for shared libraries that are simultaneously used by your process tree (perhaps multiple times) and by unrelated processes?

Answer (score 3):

I think `time -f %M` only works in recent Linux kernels (experimentally, it's not supported in 2.6.26/amd64, and it is supported in 2.6.32/i386).

[An earlier thread at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563168/monitor-a-programs-memory-usage-in-linux) didn't turn up much.

Without kernel support, monitoring memory usage is fairly hard. There are a few ways to do it:

- `LD_PRELOAD` a small library that overloads `mmap`, `sbrk` and other memory-allocating system calls (assuming you don't run any static binaries).
- `ptrace` the processes do watch memory allocation and forking.
- Watch `/proc/` (works for a single process only, and you don't know what happens between measures).

These ways all require some programming; I don't know of an existing tool.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using https://github.com/gsauthof/cgmemtime.

> cgmemtime measures the high-water RSS+CACHE memory usage of a process
>   and its descendant processes.
>
> To be able to do so it puts the process into its own cgroup.
>
> For example process A allocates 10 MiB and forks a child B that
>   allocates 20 MiB and that forks a child C that allocates 30 MiB. All
>   three processes share a time window where their allocations result in
>   corresponding RSS (resident set size) memory usage.
>
> The question now is: How much memory is actually used as a result of
>   running A?
>
> Answer: 60 MiB
>
> cgmemtime is the tool to answer such questions.

Answer (score 1):

`pmap` shows all memory allocated to a process, and even gives you the total. Detecting the child processes is harder, you can maybe combine it with `strace` but I can't think in a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The ps command can be used to measure the amount of memory that each process uses.

%MEM shows the percentage of physical memory that a process uses.  While not always the full picture it can identify processes that are responsible for system paging and swapping.

SZ shows the approximate virtual size of a process.

RSS is the Resident Set size and is the actual amount of memory that the process was using when ps was run.

Check your **man ps** page for options for listing process trees.